# No se renderiza lo que extraigo de mi api, Next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next

Estoy intentando extraer los datos de la api, en un console.log dentro de la funciòn que

exporto me consigue los datos, pero al momento de querer renderizarlos no lo hace, ni

siquiera me da los datos en un console cuando los pide dentro de esta funcion, no veo por

donde puede estar ocurriendo el error, les dejo el codigo donde pido el renderizado, la

funcion importada llama a la api, y funciona si la llamo en ella misma

```
  import { GetData } from "./peticion";
  function Categoria({ items }) {
     return (
     <>
      <div className="flex">
        {items &&
          items.map((items) => (
            <div
              key={items.id}
              className="bg-slate-200"
            >
              {/* <img
          src="/images/buso.png"
          className="w-full shadow-sm bg-white"
          alt="producto"
        /> */}
              <div className="w-full flex">
                <h5 className="font-bold">
                  {items.title}
                </h5>
                <p className="font-normal">
                  {items.descripcion}
                </p>
                <p className="italic">{items.precio}</p>
                <button className="p-2">
                  Comprar
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
         </div>
        </div>
       </section>
       </>
       );
      }
   export default Categoria;
   export async function getStaticProps() {
    let res = await GetData();
    console.log(res);
     return {
      props: { items: res },
     };
    }
```

Comment: Intenta llamar `items` a `res` así `let items = await GetData();` y luego ya solo regresas items asi: `return { props: { items }};`

Comment: no, sigue sin cambiar el resultado

Comment: Actualizacion: el problema parece estar cuando tengo que pasar de las staticprops al componente categorias, al poner un console en el staticprops, me muestra el objeto en la terminal, pero es undefined cuando lo pido en el componente

Comment: no cambia el resultado, sigue sin obtener los datos dentro de Categorias()

Comment: estube revisando, y al parecer lo que no se exporta correctamente es la funcion

Comment: Pues mencionas que si haces un `console.log` dentro de `getStaticProps` si tienes los datos, entonces no deberia haber problema, me gustaria ver si tienes la configuracion correcta para tus rutas dinamicas, si pudieras compartir una pantalla de como se ve tu directorio en especial este modulo Categoria, debe estar dentro de un archivo con algo asi como `[id].js`

Comment: Perdón, no actualize, estube leyendo la documentación y mi error era que estaba usando getStaticProps dentro de un componente, cuando debería utilizarse en una página, osea un archivo dentro de pages, movi la función a la página y renderize el archivo también en la página y funciona correctamente